# Error in playing audio file in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio

Hey I am new in iphone development.I am trying to play audio file in my app.But i am getting this error.can anyone help me to solve this.I have already added AVFoundation and CoreGraphics framework.So please help me to solve this.Thank you in advance.

Ld "/Users/keshav/Desktop/Build Files/SampleAudioCode-gedwwrowqwoobjgojkmypquuiukj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SampleAudioCode.app/SampleAudioCode" normal i386
    cd /Volumes/d/projects/sample/SampleAudioCode
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk "-L/Users/keshav/Desktop/Build Files/SampleAudioCode-gedwwrowqwoobjgojkmypquuiukj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/keshav/Desktop/Build Files/SampleAudioCode-gedwwrowqwoobjgojkmypquuiukj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist "/Users/keshav/Desktop/Build Files/SampleAudioCode-gedwwrowqwoobjgojkmypquuiukj/Build/Intermediates/SampleAudioCode.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SampleAudioCode.build/Objects-normal/i386/SampleAudioCode.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework CoreFoundation -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Users/keshav/Desktop/Build Files/SampleAudioCode-gedwwrowqwoobjgojkmypquuiukj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SampleAudioCode.app/SampleAudioCode"

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `AudioToolbox` framework as well in Xcode to remove this linker error.

Comment: Thank you For you reply.But its still no working.I mean, I can't hear any voice may be audio driver problem.can you suggest me something for that.I am using Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 (11D50) (crack version) so please advice me to solve this.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @NSP you should ask a new question for this. SO encourages one problem per question. :)